# Is there a way of accessing the RGB values of a point whose 3D coordinates are known in ARCore?

Tags: android, image-processing, yuv, arcore

I am trying to extract the RGB colour information once I know the 3D coordinates of a point cloud.

To get the point cloud, I am using the function :-

```
PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
```

After getting the point cloud, I iterate over the buffer

```
FloatBuffer points_buffer = pointCloud.getPoints();
  while(points_buffer.hasRemaining())
  {
    float x = points_buffer.get();
    float y = points_buffer.get();
    float z = points_buffer.get();
    float confidence = points_buffer.get();
  }
```

I am able to extract the coordinates of the points, and I need to store the information about the colour (RGB values) at that point along with it.

I have been trying to do it through the following approach:-

1) Save the image in each frame using:-

```
Image m_img = frame.acquireCameraImage();
```

2) Then transforming the 3D coordinates to screen coordinates using:-

[Convert 3D world (arcore anchor/pose) to its corresponding 2D screen coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026297/convert-3d-world-arcore-anchor-pose-to-its-corresponding-2d-screen-coordinates][1])

For the pose, I am using the x,y,z coordinates for the translation and the identity Quaternion for rotation.

Then I plan on looking up the values in the Bitmap.

However, I am facing the following problems.

1 )The captured image is in YUV_420_888 format, and I was unsuccessful in converting it to a bitmap in ARGB_888 format.

2) The coordinate conversion link described above sometimes gives negative values for the x-coordinate.

Is there any better way to extract the RGB values given the 3D coordinate in ARCore?